# Zsh automated forkbomb detection and mitigation

Tags: if-statement, syntax, process, fork, zsh

I am trying to write a zsh script that detects and kills a forkbomb. I know the easiest way to prevent this is to set the limit in the limits.conf file, but this assignment requires an automated detection and mitigation solution. I'm not super familiar with scripting, especially not zsh, so I'm not sure if there is a logic error or a syntax error.

My bombDestroyer.zsh file:

```
#!/bin/zsh
#
ulimit -u 20 #limit user process to 20

#Kill any process that exceeds the limit except for root
if [[ $(ulimit -u) -eq 20 ]]; then
        if [[ $(whoami) != "root" ]]; then
                echo "Fork bomb detected. Killing user's processes"
                killall -u $(whoami)
        fi
else
        echo "No fork bomb detected"
        exit 1
fi
```

I used the `chmod +x bombDestroyer.zsh` command to make it executable but when I run it with `sudo ./bombDestroyer`, nothing happens. None of the echo statements are printed and no processes are killed.
Even when the bomb is executing and the user has hundreds of processes, the zsh script does not kill the processes.
When I ran it without the second if statement, it worked (killed all root processes and thus shut down the VM), so I think it's a syntax error.

Comment: _if there is a logic error or a syntax error_ : For just checking the syntax, do a `zsh -n SCRIPTNAME`. If the syntax is OK, you will get exit code 0. Since your script obviously **did** something, it can't be a syntax error.

Comment: I don't see in your script any logic which would search for processes exceeding their limits.  However, I would expect from your code the error message _ulimit: bad option: -u_. See _man zshbuiltins_ on what options `ulimit` accepts.